# minimum of expected value

Tags: probability, inequality

let $X_k$ be the sequence of random variables. 
Is it true that
$E[\min_{1\le k\le n}X_k]\ge \min_{1\le k\le n} E[X_k]$
provided that the left hand side exist?

Comment: What do you think ? And why would the left-hand side not exist ?

Comment: I am curious that why this inequality can not be proved by Jesen? Since the minimize function is concave?@YvesDaoust

Answer (score 1):

No.

Take two uniform variables in $[-1,1]$. The minimum of the expectations is $0$, but the expectation of the minimum must be biased towards the negative.

Indeed, it is easy to show that the $\text{cdf}$ of the minimum is

$$\mathbb P(U+V\le x)=1-(1-\mathbb P(U\le x))(1-\mathbb P(V\le x))=1-\left(\frac{1-x}2\right)^2$$

giving the expectation

$$\int_{-1}^1 x\left(1-\left(\frac{1-x}2\right)^2\right)'dx=-\frac13.$$